# how do I use quote or quotation in traditionalTeX

Tags: pdftex, plain-tex, csquotes

I am trying to use \begin{quote} in traditional TeX and was wondering how this works. I have not been able to find an answer to it.  Any suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\def\Quote{%
  \par
  \begingroup
  \parindent=0pt
  \rightskip=2.2cm
  \leftskip=2.2cm
}
\def\endQuote{\par\endgroup}

I am trying to use quote in traditional \TeX\ and was wondering how this works. I 
have not been able to find an answer to it. Any suggestions are very welcome. 

\Quote
I am trying to use quote in traditional \TeX\ and was wondering how this works. I 
have not been able to find an answer to it. Any suggestions are very welcome. 
I am trying to use quote in traditional \TeX\ and was wondering how this works. I 
have not been able to find an answer to it. Any suggestions are very welcome. 
\endQuote

I am trying to use quote in traditional \TeX\ and was wondering how this works. I 
have not been able to find an answer to it. Any suggestions are very welcome. 
\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`\begin{quote}` is a LaTeX environment, not a Plain TeX macro. You can use the `\narrower` macro in Plain TeX:

```
According to {\it The \TeX book}, p.~100 you can use the {\tt narrower} macro
and the {\tt smallskip} macro to create a block quotation. Something like
this:

{\narrower\smallskip\noindent
  This paragraph will have narrower lines than the surrounding paragraphs do,
  because it uses the ``narrower'' feature of plain \TeX. The former margins
will be restored after this group ends.\smallskip}

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: actually this doesn't work on mine.

Comment: @peter, in that case you need to provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so we can see your code and what you are trying to do. "doesn't work" is not very descriptive...

Comment: I am just using the example that @David Purton has written and I don't get the "narrower" lines.

Comment: @peter, what do you get? how are you compiling my example? You should just be using `pdftex myfile.tex`. The code above is self contained, nothing else is needed.

Comment: @peter: David's example should (must, really) work compiled with tex (output to DVI) or with pdftex, luatex and xetex (output to PDF).